# Using FHIR works on AWS, How to create a resource with client-specific-ids?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hl7-fhir

We are working on FHIR(Fast Healthcare Interoperability Resources).
We have followed “FHIR works on AWS” and deployed the Cloud Formation template given by AWS in our AWS environment. Following is the template that we have deployed.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/fhir-works-on-aws/aws-cloudformation-template.html

**Requirement** : we want to maintain client specific/customized ids as primary key in the server.
**Problem** : server not allowing us to override or maintain client specific (customized) ids as primary key. Infact, in the runtime, it is generating its own ids and ignoring the ids provided by us.
Could you please let us know if there is any way to post the FHIR resource with client specific ids into FHIR server(Dynamo DB).

We have observed that by using "PUT" call(https://hl7.org/fhir/http.html#upsert), we might be able to generate the resource with customized ids as primary keys, but there is a precondition stating that "CapabilityStatement.rest.resource.updateCreate" Flag to be updated as "True".
Is there any way to update the "CapabilityStatement.rest.resource.updateCreate" flag through AWS console or by any manual process??

Comment: This appears to be a continuation of the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72140945/fhir-works-on-aws-server-not-allowing-to-keep-customized-id-as-primary-key/72141978#72141978. Please use the comments on that question to clarify what you're having trouble with, instead of creating a new question.

Comment: If a server's CapabilityStatement says "I don't support this", then it doesn't support it.  The CapabilityStatement reflects the state of the system.  It's *possible* that the system might have an internal configuration capability - you'd need to read the documentation and/or contact the system designer.  Beyond that, you're out of luck.